# Python fastapi running on 8432 err ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: python, apache, fastapi, httpd.conf

i am developing a project on fastapi running on port 8432, in the same server httpd[Apache+php] is runnning on port 443.where i made a ajax call from the httpd server to fastapi ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID is showing the console.
:8432/tafcop/get_reverify_status/8884781000:1

```
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

When i click in the https://localhost:8432/tafcop/get_reverify_status/8884781000, and accept the certificate it will work and ever works unless certificated is deleted.

How to configure this so that user should accept one time certificate.
All these certificates are of selfsigned generated using openssl